# why does match think these arms are not the same?

Tags: rust

(Instruction decode in PDP emulator)

I have a huge match set where each arm returns a function pointer and a name. Here is an extract

```
         match (inst & 0o170000) >> 12 {
            0o00 => match (inst & 0o007700) >> 6 {
                0o00 => match inst & 0o77 {
                    00 => (Cpu::halt, "halt"), 
                    01 => (Cpu::halt, "wait"),
                    02 => (Cpu::halt, "rti"),
                    03 => (Cpu::halt, "bpt"),
                    04 => (Cpu::halt, "iot"),
```

every arm of these matches says (Cpu::halt,"xxx"). This happily compiles. But of course I want real functions in there so I changed the first one.

```
         match (inst & 0o170000) >> 12 {
            0o00 => match (inst & 0o007700) >> 6 {
                0o00 => match inst & 0o77 {
                    00 => (Cpu::mov, "halt"), 
                    01 => (Cpu::halt, "wait"),
                    02 => (Cpu::halt, "rti"),
                    03 => (Cpu::halt, "bpt"),
                    04 => (Cpu::halt, "iot"),
```

Both halt and mov have the same signatures

```
impl Cpu{
    pub fn halt(&mut self, z:Word)->Result<(), Exception>{Ok(())}

    pub fn mov(&mut self, z:Word) ->Result<(), Exception>{
        let (mut ss,mut dd) = self.decode_ssdd(z, false)?;
        let t = self.fetch_word(&mut ss)?;
        self.psw &= !statusflags::PS_V;
        self.set_status(t);
        self.store_word(&mut dd, t)?;
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

but rustc then complains

```
error[E0308]: `match` arms have incompatible types
  --> src\cpu.rs:83:31
   |
81 |                       0o00 => match inst & 0o77 {
   |  _____________________________-
82 | |                         00 => (Cpu::mov, "halt"), 
   | |                               ------------------ this is found to be of type `(for<'r> fn(&'r mut cpu::Cpu, u16) -> std::result::Result<(), common::Exception> {instructions::<impl cpu::Cpu>::mov}, &str)`
83 | |                         01 => (Cpu::halt, "wait"),
   | |                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected fn item, found a different fn item
84 | |                         02 => (Cpu::halt, "rti"),
...  |
90 | |                         _ => unreachable!(),
91 | |                     },
   | |_____________________- `match` arms have incompatible types
   |
   = note: expected type `(for<'r> fn(&'r mut cpu::Cpu, _) -> std::result::Result<_, _> {instructions::<impl cpu::Cpu>::mov}, &str)`
             found tuple `(for<'r> fn(&'r mut cpu::Cpu, _) -> std::result::Result<_, _> {instructions::<impl cpu::Cpu>::halt}, &'static str)`
```

the essential part of the error seems to be the last 2 lines that says the difference between the tuples it found is that one is (fn, &str) and the other is (fn, &'static str). And yet they are identical except the function name.

I also note the the earlier error says "expected fn item, found a different fn item" but thats not what the last 2 lines say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider this simplified case:

```
pub struct Exception{}

pub struct Cpu {}

impl Cpu{
    pub fn halt(&mut self)->Result<(), Exception>{Ok(())}
    pub fn mov(&mut self) ->Result<(), Exception>{Ok(())}
}
```

Then this compiles OK:

```
pub fn foo(cpu:&mut Cpu, i:i32) -> Result<(), Exception> {
    let f = match i {
        0 => Cpu::halt,
        _ => Cpu::mov,
    };
    f(cpu)
}
```

But this generates the same error that you see

```
pub fn bar(cpu:&mut Cpu, i:i32) -> Result<(), Exception> {
    let f = match i {
        0 => (Cpu::halt,"halt"),
        _ => (Cpu::mov,"mov"),
    };
    f.0(cpu)
}
```

It seems like in the `bar` case the compiler is unable to deduce the type for the tuple returned from the match. We can find out what type the compiler is deducing for f in the `foo` case by adding `q:() = f;` and looking at the error message. It is

```
17 |     let q:() = f;
   |           --   ^ expected `()`, found fn pointer
   |           |
   |           expected due to this
   |
   = note: expected unit type `()`
             found fn pointer `for<'r> fn(&'r mut Cpu) -> std::result::Result<(), Exception>`
```

We can then explicitly state that type for the tuple to get `bar` to compile (but we can remove the `for<'r> ... 'r` bit)

```
pub fn bar(cpu:&mut Cpu, i:i32) -> Result<(), Exception> {
    let f: (fn(&mut Cpu) -> Result<(), Exception>, &str) = match i {
        0 => (Cpu::halt, "halt"),
        _ => (Cpu::mov, "mov"),
    };
    f.0(cpu)
}
```

I'd personally use a `type` statement to get rid of the noise

```
type CpuFn = fn(&mut Cpu) -> Result<(), Exception>;
pub fn bar(cpu:&mut Cpu, i:i32) -> Result<(), Exception> {
    let f: (CpuFn, &str) = match i {
        0 => (Cpu::halt, "halt"),
        _ => (Cpu::mov, "mov"),
    };
    f.0(cpu)
}
```

You can see a complete working version [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=53353b481e183252dff4d5b2f8ce6894)

---

ASIDE:

It is worth noting that using the `q:() = Cpu::halt` trick we see that the type of `Cpu::halt` is `fn item for<'r> fn(&'r mut Cpu) -> Result<(), Exception> {Cpu::halt}` which is not the same as that returned from the match in `foo`. The compiler is combining two branches with types

```
fn(&mut Cpu) -> Result<(), Exception> {Cpu::halt}
```

and

```
fn(&mut Cpu) -> Result<(), Exception> {Cpu::mov}
```

into a common type.

```
fn(&mut Cpu) -> Result<(), Exception>
```

but is unwilling to combine the types

```
(fn(&mut Cpu) -> Result<(), Exception> {Cpu::halt}, &str)
(fn(&mut Cpu) -> Result<(), Exception> {Cpu::mov}, &str)
```

into

```
(fn(&mut Cpu) -> Result<(), Exception>, &str)
```

I can't find any information on what conversions are performed on the return values of the match branches in general, nor can I find any information on the difference between `fn item` and `fn pointer` types in rust.

Comment: wow, ty. I had the type definition ready but was not assigning the match output yet, I thought 'lets take it one step at a time'. Seems like a bug really, I mean every arm has the same str and yet it thinks one is str and the other is static str

Comment: Looks like same issue as [#74231](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/74231).

Comment: I _think_ the `&str` and `&'statc str` is a red herring - the real issue is the types of the function pointers. If you can isolate a version that throws an error for the `&str` case without the function pointers that would be very interesting.

Comment: anyway - fixed for me - ty

Comment: Difference between `fn item` and `fn pointer` is simple: `fn item` is a type unique to concrete function (which allows compiler to optimize calls through it), and `fn pointer` is, well, just a pointer, with no knowledge of the concrete function behind it (besides the signature).

Comment: @Cerberus That was what I assumed the case to be, but could not find anything concrete about that. All the documentation about the primitive `fn` type doesn't mention the difference nor what kinds of conversions are supported between these types - and I think is really aiming at `fn pointer`.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson Here's the (hopefully) relevant part of Rust reference: https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/function-item.html